# Trouble Setting column in 1 table with case select of 2nd table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I feel like I'm going about this wrong. I'm sort of(?) new to SQL Server and fairly proficient at C#.

I have two tables set as shown:

Table 1: `OOPool`

```
[PO#]        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
[PartNumber] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[DateRec]    DATE         NOT NULL,
[DateDue]    DATE         NOT NULL,
[QTY]        INT          NOT NULL,
[Priority]   SMALLINT     NULL,
[CycleValue] INT          NULL
```

Table 2: `PORecord`

```
[PO#]           BIGINT       NOT NULL,
[PartNumber]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[DateReceived]  DATE         NULL,
[DateDue]       DATE         NULL,
[QTYOpen]       SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
[DateCompleted] DATE         NULL,
[QTYCompleted]  SMALLINT     NULL,
[WHC]           VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Completed]     BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_Completed] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[IsHOT]         BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_IsHOT] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[LOS]           BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_LOS] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[IsCO]          BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_IsCO] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[IsPP]          BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_IsPP] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[OutsidePick]   BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_OutsidePick] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[Machining]     BIT          CONSTRAINT [DF_PORecord_Machining] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[RecentUser]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[LastUpdate]    DATE         NULL
```

`OOPool` is used for the open orders, and all of the `NOT NULL` data is supplied in another `INSERT INTO` command. I'm now trying to supply the `Priority` column value by comparing the `IsHot`, `IsCO`, and `LOS` column values to return a single value.

This is what I tried:

```
UPDATE OOPool
SET Priority = (SELECT CASE
    WHEN LOS = 1 THEN 0
    WHEN (IsHot = 1) and (IsCO = 1) THEN 1
    WHEN (IsCO = 1) and (IsHot = 0) THEN 2
    WHEN (IsHOT = 1) and (IsCo = 0) THEN 3
    ELSE 4
    END
FROM PORecord
WHERE PORecord.PO# = OOPool.PO#)
```

Currently, I'm getting the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows ...

I'm thinking of going back and restructuring my `PORecord` table to only have 1 column named `Priority` to match `OOPool` and then have the application supply the comparison result before pushing to the DB, but that's a lot of work (I would also have to convert the current data).

Am I just doing it wrong? Or am I going about this wrong like I thought?

**EDIT:** It turns out I was right. I was doing it wrong, and it was due to my lack of knowledge of `JOIN`.

I used Pradeep's response, and it worked perfectly.

Code used:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Priority = B.col
FROM OOPool A
    JOIN (SELECT PO#,
              CASE
                  WHEN LOS = 1 THEN 0
                  WHEN (IsHot = 1) AND (IsCO = 1) THEN 1
                  WHEN (IsCO = 1) and (IsHot = 0) THEN 2
                  WHEN (IsHot = 1) and (IsCO = 0) THEN 3
                  ELSE 4
              END col
          FROM PORecord) b
ON b.PO# = A.PO#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be lyk this

```
UPDATE A 
SET    A.priority = B.col 
FROM   oopool A 
       JOIN (SELECT po#, 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN los = 1 THEN 0 
                      WHEN ( ishot = 1 ) 
                           AND ( isco = 1 ) THEN 1 
                      WHEN ( isco = 1 ) 
                           AND ( ishot = 0 ) THEN 2 
                      WHEN ( ishot = 1 ) 
                           AND ( isco = 0 ) THEN 3 
                      ELSE 4 
                    END COL 
             FROM   porecord) B 
         ON B.po# = A.po#
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I guess I know what I need to research and practice more on... JOIN!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN` in your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE p
SET Priority = 
    CASE
        WHEN r.LOS = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN r.IsHot = 1 and r.IsCO = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN r.IsCO = 1 and r.IsHot = 0 THEN 2
        WHEN r.IsHOT = 1 and r.IsCo = 0 THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END
FROM OOPool p
    JOIN PORecord r ON p.[PO#] = r.[PO#]
```